# How to Reset a nested nav graph Android

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

I have a bottom nav with 2 tabs. Each tab is a separate nested nav graph. I am in the second one and when navigate inside it from the start destination to another fragment, If go to the first tab and then come back to the second, it starts from the fragment I reached not the start destination. I need it to start from the start destination again since I am fetching the data there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I came to a solution to **clear** the **saved state** using

```
findNavController().clearBackStack(id_of_the_nested_graph)
```

Apparently, it won't clear **itself automatically** anymore.

Note: not clearing might cause `IllegalSateException` when updating the nav graph

Another more proficient solution is to add
**app:popUpToSaveState="false"  app:restoreState="false"**

to the action in app_navigation